# Habilitar página de erro php

Tags: php, apache

já vi várias tentativas de habilitar páginas de erro no apache/php mas nenhuma funcionou aqui.

tenho arquivo ***.htaccess*** e nele tenho as seguintes linhas:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(index|index/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Fiz o teste com una página inexistente em localhost!

Porque o apache não redireciona para as páginas de erro?

Também tentei assim no .htaccess e não deu

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
    ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

    RewriteRule ^(index|index\/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Já reestartei o Apache e nada

Setei AllowOverride para All em todas ocorrências do httpd.conf.
tirei o comentário da linha mod_rewrite.

Nada!

Comment: Vc está colocando ele fora da tag mod_rewrite, nunca vai funcionar. E está colocando antes de RewriteEngine On, ou seja não está usando ele dentro do modo de reescrita.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seu problema se resolve assim:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

    RewriteRule ^(index|index\/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
```

Porém você pode ao invés de colocar `ErrorDocument`, utilizar somente um redirecionamento:

```
Redirect 401 /401.php
Redirect 403 /403.php
Redirect 404 /404.php
Redirect 500 /500.php
```

Entretanto, acredito que você não esteja sabendo tratar a saída das ocorrências de erros.

Uma das formas de fazer tratamento de erro não necessita que seja feito um redirecionamento pelo `.htaccess`, basta implementar um método através da linguagem, alguns Frameworks já incluem controlador para tratamento de erro. Mas uma maneira simples que você poderia fazer para contornar o problema é criar um método conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

    function errorReportingHandler($code = NULL) {
            $return = array(401, 403, 404, 500);
            if ($code !== NULL) {
               if (in_array($code, $return)) {
                   header('Location: ' . $return[$code].'.php');
               } else {
                   header('Location: default_errors.php');
               }
            }
     }
     $GLOBALS['http_response_code'] = $code;
     errorReportingHandler($code);
?>
```

Para mais informações, sugiro acessar a **[Documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)** que fala sobre tratativa de erros.

Comment: Não funcionou. Acredita? Será mesmo no arquivo .htaccess

Comment: Acho que funcionou sim. Mas não posso transferir para 404.php que não acha embora a página esteja lá. Precisa ter extensão .html. Alguma correção quanto à isso?

Comment: Puxa vida. Agora em vez de abrir a página index.html que é a nova página de erro ele esta exibindo it works!

Comment: Descobri. O problema é que é preciso passar o endereço completo da página de erro. Tipo http://..... Será que existe uma regra para passar só o caminho relativo?
E será que existe uma forma de e vez de redirecionar para a página 404.php, o endereço da barra de endereços permanecer o mesmo e a página 404;php ser incluída?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, deve solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Quando editar diz aqui que editou pois acabei de testar e ainda não funcionou!

Comment: Já editei @CarlosRocha. Veja se  a solução resolve seu problema.